# Password/Key Management for multiple machines in emacs

Tags: tramp, ftp, passwords

I log into numerous machines as part of my job (+- 20 per day). I only spend a few days/weeks with each machine. Many run ftp only.

For seamless access Tramp is amazing, but it is the *managing* of these server's access by hand that has become tedious.

I manage a .netrc and a .ssh/config by hand, along with any keys. Often a password/key will change during my time with the machine, and I will have to re-edit the files.

Is there an effective solution for managing (machines/passwords/keys) from within emacs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use a simple password manager called [pass](http://www.passwordstore.org/). It offers a simple command line interface with is ideal for integrating with Emacs. The backing store is a GPG encrypted GIT repo. It actually ships with an [Emacs package](http://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/contrib/emacs/password-store.el) although I don't use it. My interface is laughably simple:

```
(defun my-fixup-gpg-agent (frame)
  "Tweak DISPLAY and GPG_TTY environment variables as appropriate to `FRAME'."
  (when (fboundp 'keychain-refresh-environment)
    (keychain-refresh-environment))
  (if (display-graphic-p frame)
      (setenv "DISPLAY" (terminal-name frame))
    (setenv "GPG_TTY" (terminal-name frame))
    (setenv "DISPLAY" nil)))

(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions 'my-fixup-gpg-agent)

;; Simple caching
(defvar my-cached-passwords
  nil
  "Cache of passwords. Stored in plain text so you only want to cache
  them if of low value.")

(defun my-pass-password (pass-name &optional cache)
  "Return the password for the `PASS-NAME'."
  (let ((cached-pass (assoc-default pass-name my-cached-passwords)))
    (if cached-pass
        cached-pass
      (when (selected-frame)
        (my-fixup-gpg-agent (selected-frame))
        (let ((new-pass (chomp
                         (shell-command-to-string
                          (format "pass %s" pass-name)))))
          (when (and new-pass cache)
            (add-to-list 'my-cached-passwords (cons pass-name new-pass)))
          new-pass)))))
```

Comment: Pass wasn't entirely what I was looking for, but I chose your answer because I feel mine is an edge case. But your answer is far more useful to the community.

Comment: @Gambo well as a git repo it's fairly easy to distribute. You do need to distribute keys though. I haven't experimented with it's multi-key support.

Answer (score 3):

Tramp uses the auth-sources backend for managing passwords. It needs some specialized entries in .authinfo, like

```
 machine melancholia port scp login daniel password geheim
```

Read the Tramp manual, chapter "Password handling", for details.

auth-sources have also some functionality to create password entries on-the-fly. I've never tried this functionality with Tramp, but maybe you investigate a little bit.

Comment: Starting with Tramp 2.4.0, Tramp saves also new passwords via auth-sources.